# Import large csv of rows into database without running out of memory

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm new to node and the whole non-blocking IO paradigm. I'm importing a CSV of 1.8 million rows to a database. It works if I truncate the CSV to a smaller number of rows, but I run out of memory for larger numbers of rows. My ORM is [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/) which is async / promise based.

Here's a simplified snippet of my code:

```
csv()
.from.path(thePath)
.on('record', function(row,index){
  models.meshblock.findOrCreate({
      where: {item_code: row[0]},
  })
})
```

I think the problem is that as I'm streaming the CSV in, I'm sending off all these async database queries, faster than they can be dealt with, so memory is used faster than it's freed.

If there were just a way to say "finish this row, save it to the database, wait til it's all done, free up the memory, then continue" then the process should be super slow, but at least should be able to complete without running out of memory.

Is my assessment of what the problem is correct? And, how can I get around it and import the rows without running out of memory?

Comment: Does `findOrCreate` have a callback?  If so, maybe you could come up with a make-shift semaphore so you can batch `findOrCreate`s.

Comment: findOrCreate returns a promise. So yeah, I'll try pausing the csv stream until the first 1000 promises resolve, then continuing it. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most *efficient* way is to use database-specific mechanisms. Examples:

- **MySQL/MariaDB**: [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)
- **Postgresql**: [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)
- **SQL Server**: [`bcp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)
- **Oracle**: [`sqlldr`](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aLoader_FAQ#How_does_one_use_the_SQL.2ALoader_utility.3F)

Comment: Unfortunately there's some business logic that needs to take place on each row, so it's not quite that simple.